# Why are sent emails not deleted when I delete a conversation in Apple Mail?

Tags: macos, mail.app, imap

According to the [docs](https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/delete-emails-mlhlp1001/mac), when a conversation is deleted, `all of the messages in a conversation will be deleted`.

Somehow, when I delete a conversation, sent emails are not deleted which creates orphans in the "Sent" folder.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

These are two totally different entities.

The confusion comes in from a misunderstanding of how messaging works.  It' helps to understand the concepts:

- Your Inbox are what you received via your incoming server
- "Conversations" is a collation of related messages you've received by your email client.  There's no conversation the server is aware of.
- Sent Messages are messages that were transmitted via your outgoing server

What's important to know is that as far as your server is concerned, there's no such thing as a "conversation."  There are just messages in folder (Inbox, Outbox, Sent, Junk, etc.).

**"Deleting the conversation" is nothing more than a feature that was implemented to help organize your Inbox.**

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to break this down Allan. I am aware of conversions being an client-layer abstraction (if I don't find a solution. I am considering writing an IMAP CLI to implement the feature). That being said, my expectation was that Apple Mail would delete the whole conversation including both inbox and sent messages. Do you know why this isn't the case? Do you know of a workaround?

Comment: There's no work around because it's not a problem.   An app not doing what you personally expected, doesn't mean it a bug or a failure. It's also not just a "client layer abstraction."  It's a function applied to your Inbox *alone* because it shows up in no other location within your email database.